# License violation detected. Unlicensed module(s) detected

Tags: appcelerator

I bought and installed a none Appcelerator module from the Marketplace. Now Ti Studio says there is a License violation and I need to be a subscriber to use the module.

I am a community member and not Indie. Why cannot I use modules that are not made by Ti from the Marketplace?

Answer (score 1):

Just closing out this unanswered question with the answer, which that there was a bug, and it's now fixed:

> The issue is now fixed, and the module is now updated in the repo. Let me know if you have any more issues.

[Source](https://archive.appcelerator.com/question/125875/license-violation-detected-unlicensed-modules-detected).

Comment: @Jonathan Clark: Noticed this question had been answered, so posted the answer/link -- also, just a heads up there's a new StackExchange Appc-Q&A-site, visit http://bit.ly/AppcMentor, click **"Follow It!" to support the effort** - Need 52ppl to go fwd. Feel free to [retweet the message too](https://twitter.com/#!/AppcMentor/status/196969284889624576).